Difference between %time vs %%time vs %timeit %%timeit in Jupyter Notebook
Help me in finding out the exact difference between time and timeit magic commands in jupyter notebook.
%time

a="stack overflow"
time.sleep(2)
print(a)


It shows only some micro seconds, But I added sleep time as 2 seconds


Did you try searching the documentation? https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time One or two percent signs is line magic or cell magic

Magics that are prefixed with double percentage signs (%%) are considered cell magics. This differs from line magics which are prefixed with a single percentage sign (%).
It follows that,

time is used to time the execution of code either at a line level (%) or cell level (%%).
timeit is similar but runs the code multiple times to provide more accurate and statistically significant timing information.

The key distinction is that %time and %%time (docs) measure the execution time of code once, while %timeit and %%timeit (docs) measure the execution time of code multiple times to give an average time and standard deviation.
Hence,
%%time

a="stack overflow"
time.sleep(2)
print(a)

This output shows both the CPU time and the wall time. The wall time includes the 2 seconds sleep time, while the CPU time accounts for the actual processing time.
Replacing %%time with %time will show the CPU time and the wall time for the next single line that is executed.

Thank you for the explanation, Will you please explain the difference between cpu time and wall time

@DhamodharanR As explained in this post, CPU time refers to the actual time the CPU spends processing instructions for a specific task. It only includes the time the CPU is actively working on the task/user code. Wall time, on the other hand, is the total elapsed time from the start to the completion of the task. Essentially, CPU time measures active processing time, while wall time measures total elapsed time.
